# Why does a*a match aaa?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, regex-greedy

I am using python3 re module - I find that `a*a` matches `aaa`. I thought that regex was greedy by default (unless we override it to be lazy with `?`) - so, `a*` would have matched the entire string, and the trailing `a` in the pattern would fail. However, it matches:

```
$ import re
$ re.match(r'a*a', 'aaa')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='aaa'>
```

Should this not fail?

Comment: greedy doesn't mean that it _must_ swallow everything it can, it only means it _prefers to_.

Comment: Recommended research: "Backtracking" in regular expressions

Comment: Your expectation is called a possessive match. Regarding to your engine this feature may or may not be available. In PCRE `a*+a` wouldn't match `aaa` because `a*+` consumes every `a` possessively (doesn't backtrack). But I marked two questions on greediness and backtracking that will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *does* initially attempt to match the entire string, but repetition will *backtrack* if a match fails. After the `a*` initially matching the entire string, the regex tries to match the next token, the single `a` This fails, so then the `a*` *backtracks* back a character (so that it only matches `aa` rather than `aaa`). This time, the last token, the single `a`, *is* fulfilled, so a match is found.

Greedyness doesn't mean that the regular expression will only match if the repeated token is allowed to match the whole rest of the string. It *will* if it can, but it'll backtrack if it can't.

Even if greedy repetition with `*` backtracks down to zero length, there's no problem, because `*` means match *zero or more* times. (by contrast, repeating with `+`, if it backtracks down to zero length, the regular expression will fail completely, because `+` means that *at least one repetition* is required)

Answer (score 0):

`a*` means zero or more "a" characters. `a*a` means "zero or more "a" characters followed by an "a". "aaa" is indeed "zero or more a characters followed by an "a" since "aa" meets the criteria of "zero or more".